# Why do we need total order across view changes in consensus protocols?

Tags: protocols, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system, consensus

In their famous [article](https://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs426/2012/bib/castro02practical.pdf), Miguel Castro and Barbara Liskov justify the commit phase of the PBFT consensus protocol like this:

> This ensures that replicas agree on a total order for requests in the
> same view but **it is not sufficient to ensure a total order for
> requests across view changes**. Replicas may collect prepared
> certificates in different views with the same sequence number and
> different requests. The commit phase solves this problem as follows.
> Each replica i multicasts <COMMIT, v, n, i>_{α_i} saying it has the
> prepared certificate and adds this message to its log. Then each
> replica collects messages until it has a quorum certificate with 2 f +
> 1 COMMIT messages for the same sequence number n and view v from
> different replicas (including itself). We call this certificate the
> committed certificate and say that the request is committed by the
> replica when it has both the prepared and committed certificates.

But why exactly do we need to guarantee total order *across view changes*?
If a leader/primary replica fails and triggers a view change, wouldn't it suffice to discard everything from the previous view? What situation does the commit phase prevent that this solution does not?

Apologies if this is too obvious. I'm new to distributed systems and I haven't found any source which directly answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a conceptual reason for this. The system appears to a client as a black box. The whole idea of this box is to provide reliable access to some service, thus, it should mask the failures of a particular replica. Otherwise, if you discard everything at each view change, clients will constantly lose their data. So basically, your solution simply contradicts the specification. The commit phase is needed exactly to prevent such kind of situations. If the request is "accepted" only when there are 2f + 1 COMMIT messages, then, even if all f replicas are faulty, the remaining nodes can recover all committed requests, this provides durable access to the system.

There is also a technical reason. In theory the system is asynchronous, this means that you can't even guarantee that the view change will occur only as a result of a failure. Some replicas may only suspect that the leader is faulty and change the view. With your solution it is possible that the system discards everything it is accepted even if non of replicas is faulty.

If you're new to distributed systems I suggest you to have a look at the classic protocols tolerating non-Byzantine failures (e.g., Paxos), they are simpler but solves the problems in the similar way.

#### Edit

When I say "clients constantly lose their data" it is a bit more than it sounds. I'm talking about the impact of a particular client request to the system. Let's take a key-value store. A clinet `A` associates some `value` to some `key` via our "black box". The "black box" now orders this request with respect to any other concurrent (or simply parallel) requests. It then replicates it across all replicas and finally notifies `A`. Without commit phase there is no ordering and at two different views our "black box" can chose two different order of execution of client requests. That being said, the following is possible:

1. at a time `t`, `A` associates `value` to `key` and the "box" approves this,
2. at the time `t+1`, `B` associates `value_2` to `key` and the "box" approves this,
3. at the time `t+2`, `C` reads `value_2` from `key`,
4. view change (invisible to clients),
5. at the time `t+3`, `D` reads `value` from `key`.

Note that (5) is possible not because the "box" is not aware of `value_2` (as you mentioned the value itself can be resubmitted) but because it is not aware that previously it first wrote `value` and then overwrote it with `value_2`. At the new view, the system needs somehow order those two requests but no luck, the decision is not coherent with the past.

The eventual synchrony is a way to guarantee liveness of the protocols, however, it cannot prevent the situations described above. Eventual synchrony states that eventually your system will behave much like the synchronous one, but you don't know when, before that time any kind of weird things can happen. If during the asynchronous period a safety property is violated, then obviously the whole system is not safe.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand the conceptual reason and the contradiction. Couldn't we safely abandon the concept in real life though? E.g. in many blockchain-based systems, information/transactions can be lost but the system adapts by resubmitting them. As for the technical reason, I'm assuming you are mentioning the FLP result (https://groups.csail.mit.edu/tds/papers/Lynch/jacm85.pdf)? If so, PBFT circumvents it by assuming eventual synchony, i.e. message delays in the system are bounded. Hence, failures could be safely detected using a long-enough timeout.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was a bit confusing, check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The output of PBFT should not be one log per view, but rather an ever-growing global log to which every view tries to contribute new 'blocks'.

The equivalent notion in a blockchain is that each block proposer, or block miner, must append to the current blockchain, instead of starting its new blockchain from scratch. I.e. new blocks must respect previous transactions, the same way new views must respect previous views.

If the total ordering is not consistent across views, then we lose the property above.

In fact if we force a view change after every sequence number in PBFT, it looks a lot like blockchain, but with a much more complicated recovery/safety mechanism (in part since PBFT blocks don't commit to the previous block, so we need to agree on each of them individually)